# Cakephp How to retrieve data from GET submit

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm passing a search data on method GET like that:

```
example.com/posts/?q=foo
```

I'm trying retrive this data on controller doing this:

```
$this->params['q'];
```

but is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHP specifice function for accessing query strings:

```
$this->request->query['q'];
```

Reference: [Link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're using CakePHP 1.3. If the submission was made using Cake's Form Helper, it should be something like..

```
$this->params['data']['q']
```

or if you explicitly wrote your own HTML code for the form,

```
$this->params['url']['q']
```

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP has [simple helpers](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html) that let you access parameters.

---

For `GET` parameters you can use:

```
/users/search?age=23
$this->request->query['age']; // 23
```

---

For `POST` parameters you can use:

```
$this->request->data('age'); // 23
```